# Laravel - Eloquent log record before and after changing it

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a simple question, whenever I use Eloquent to edit a record in the DB, I'd like to be able to log the values of this row before and after the save.

My solution so far:

- I have a parent model class that extends Eloquent: App\Models\Model.php
- Then all my other models extend this Model.php, so inside this file, I'm overriding eloquent save() method.

But by the time, the save method is called, the eloquent builder object has new values, the old ones have been overwritten.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: Use existing tools like https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable or https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/revisionable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the model events for this, there are many events like `saving`, `updating`, `deleting` ... for more details [look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events)

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

  protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();  // don't forget to call the parent boot method
    //On saving
    static::saving(
      function($record)
      {
        $dirty = $record->getDirty();
        foreach ($dirty as $field => $newdata)
        {
          $olddata = $record->getOriginal($field);
          if ($olddata != $newdata)
          {
            // Do what it takes here :)
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, looks nice! But how do I get the raw sql for this ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What do you need the executed query ??

Comment: So you can use `DB::getQueryLog()` for that you can enabel it using `DB::enableQueryLog();` :)